# how to read a line and save multiple parameters into variables separated by ;?

Tags: perl, file, variables

So lets say I have a file.txt, this documents Syntax is like this:

```
"1;22;333;'4444';55555",
```

I now want my code to do the following:

1. open the file = already done
2. read line and save each Parameter separated by `;` into a variable like ( $one = 1, $two = 22, $three = 333, $four = '4444', $five = 55555; )
3. this step would be writing the variables into a DB but thats done already
4. Loop until all lines of the file are done

So I actually Need help with Step 2, i think I am able to do the Loop and DB code. Do you guys have any ideas or tips how I could do this? beginnerfriendly would be nice so I can learn out of it.

```
       foreach $file (@file){               
           $currentfile = "$currentdir\\$file";
           open(my $reader, "<", $currentfile) or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
           ?????
           close $reader;
       }
```

Comment: You can use an Array instead of variables for every column

Comment: And indeed - you _should_ at any point where you've 'numbered' your variables.

Comment: You should be using Text::CSV_XS. That will handle the quoted fields too.

Answer (score 2):

If you're just doing 'numbered fields' then you should be thinking 'array':

```
use Data::Dumper;
while ( <$reader> ) {  
    chomp;
    my @row = split /;/; 
    print Dumper \@row;
}
```

This will give you an array that you can access - e.g. `$row[0]` for the first element.

```
$VAR1 = [
          '1',
          '22',
          '333',
          '\'4444\'',
          '55555'
        ];
```

If you *know* what the headers are 'named' and prefer to work on names you can do something similar with a hash:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my @cols = qw ( id value fish name sprout ); 

while ( <DATA> ) {
    my %row;
    chomp;
    @row{@cols} = split /;/;
    print Dumper \%row;
}

__DATA__
1;22;333;'4444';55555
```

This gives instead:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'fish' => '333',
          'name' => '\'4444\'',
          'id' => '1',
          'value' => '22',
          'sprout' => '55555'
        };
```

Note - hashes are unordered, but their whole point is that you don't need to care about the 'order' - just `print $row{name},"\n";`

Answer (score 1):

You need to read from the filehandle `$reader`, line by line. See the tutorial [`perlopentut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlopentut.html) and the full reference [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html). 
Then you [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) each line by the separator `;`, what returns a list which you assign to an array.

```
open my $reader, "<", $currentfile or die "Failed to open file: $!\n";
while (my $line = <$reader>) {
    chomp($line);
    my @params = split ';', $line;
    # do something with @params, it will be overwritten on next iteration
}
close $reader;
```

The *diamond operator* `<>` reads from a filehandle, `<$fh>`, returning a line at a time. See about it [`in perlop`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators). When there are no more lines it returns `undef` and looping stops. You may assign the string that it returns to a variable which you declare (`my $line`), which then exists only within the body of the `while` loop. If you don't, but do `while (<$fh>)` instead, the line is assigned to the [`special variable`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#General-Variables) `$_`, which is default for many things in Perl.

The [`chomp`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp.html) removes the linefeed (new line) from the end of the line.

Note that `'4444'` from your example is *not* a number and cannot be used as such.

Alternatively, you can take a reference to the array with parameters on each line, and put it in another array which thus will in the end contain all lines.

```
my @all_params;
while (my $line = <$reader>) {
   my @params = split ';', $line;
   push @all_params, \@params;
}
```

Now `@all_params` has elements which are references, each to an array with parameters for one line. For how to work with references see the tutorial [`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and the Cookbook on complex data structures, [`perldsc`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).

The following is more complex but let me mention it since it's a bit of an idiom. You can do the above in one statement

```
my @all_params = map { [ split ';', $_ ] } <$reader>;
```

This uses [`map`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html), which applies the code in `{ ... }` to each element of the list that is submitted to it, returning a list. So it takes a list and returns the processed list. The `[...]` inside makes an *anonymous array*, equivalent to the reference we took of an array previously. The filehandle `<$reader>`returns all lines of the file in one list when invoked in the *list context*, which is in this case imposed by `map` (since it must receive a list).

---

An important one: *always start your programs with*

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
```

The order of these doesn't really matter. Mostly you'll see `use strict;` first.

Then your loop over filenames need be `foreach my $file (@file) { ... }` and you must *declare* all variables, so `my $currentfile = ...`.